# Azure synapse dedicated SQL pools exports to ADLS storage account via polybase have .parq extensions instead of .parquet

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, polybase

Azure synapse dedicated SQL pools exports to ADLS storage account via polybase have .parq extensions instead of .parquet extensions.

[image]

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [SomeExternalDataSourcename]
WITH(TYPE=HADOOP, LOCATION=N'abfss://containername@storageaccountname.dfs.core.windows.net/foldername') ;

CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT [ff_Parquet]
WITH (FORMAT_TYPE = PARQUET)

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [staging_schema].[table]
WITH(LOCATION='folder/schema_table', DATA_SOURCE=[SomeExternalDataSourcename], FILE_FORMAT=[ff_Parquet])
AS
SELECT *
FROM [schema].[table];

The result is below

[image]

we were expecting .parquet extension. Is there anyway to generate exports directly with .parquet extensions ?

Comment: Could you explain how the code and results are related?  the script generates the external table in sql pool. But the result page looks like storage account.

Comment: External data source is mapped to the storage account hence they are exported to ADLS storage account & scripts are being executed at dedicated SQL pool.

Answer (score 0):

Dedicated SQL pool creates `.parq` file only when using externat tables to create a file. I tried and got the `.parq` extension file only. When searched for similar issue, got [this in Microsoft QnA platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1200090/possible-bug-or-issue-in-synapse-dedicated-sql-poo) . Unfortunately, the file extension cannot be changed to the standard ".parquet" extension in the ADLS gen2 using dedicated SQL pool. Workaround is to rename the files only. You can use ADF pipeline to rename the file.

- Get the list of files using `get metadata activity`.
- Then take the for-each activity and inside for-each take the copy activity. Take the source files that has `.parq` as extension in the file name from the get metadata activity output. In the sink dataset , split the source data filename with the `dot(.)` symbol and give the `<filename>.parquet` as the filename.
- Delete the source files using delete activity. Delete activity is to be in sequential with copy activity.
- Execute the pipeline.

You can log your feedback  about this  in [Microsoft azure feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/9b9ba8e4-0825-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8) platform.

**Reference:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1200090/possible-bug-or-issue-in-synapse-dedicated-sql-poo